Strange issue with ssh
I got a strange one for everyone. I got a laptop that I am using a USB Ethernet Adapter, TP-Link. I can ssh into into the laptop with the USB Adapter, but if I turn on wifi on the laptop, suddenly I can no longer ssh into the laptop.
I am using UFW, and I have checked. UFW is setup for OpenSSH, because again it work USB Adapter.
Why would ssh not work when wifi is turned on? What can I check?

Are you using static IPs on both interfaces? Did you try connecting to the IP address that got assigned to the Wi-Fi?  It is really hard to say what your problem is without knowing details of your installation, IP address(es), etc.

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, that what our IT Department has stated we can use. It' running on a Dell Percision. If you need more information, please ask what would be useful.

No, both are on DHCP. We can't assign static, our network team not kin to that. It's just strange that if WIFI is off, we can connect via ssh. Now, both have IP addresses.

You might need to set your SSH server to listen on the specific IP address https://www.simplified.guide/ssh/listen-ip that way when the new IP that the WiFi is doing doesn't overtake the server being confused.  As I asked above, did you try connecting on the IP address that the WiFi gets to make sure that the SSH server is still working properly?
